# Model::all() works with tinker and serve but not in the route

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get all data from the database. It's returning an empty array if I use Laravel Homestead mapped site, **but it works fine with**:

```
php artisan serve
php artisan tinker
```

I can't find any mistake. I made migration, model and controller. Homestead.yaml is okay (mapping and database name are fine), /etc/hosts also, updated .env file. I tried different solutions I found here, including:

```
protected $table 
   
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear

reinstalling mysql
```

I did not work. And even with:

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
vagrant provision
```

**Is there any solution to fix this or should I use "php artisan serve" ?**

I am using Linux, VirtualBox, Homestead v10.9.1, PHP 7.4.7, Laravel Framework 7.17.2

Comment: How are you populating the database prior to loading the data? Is homestead using the same database as php artisan serve?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper, thank you for your response. I populated the database table via tinker (made a new instance of the model, inserted and saved it). On phpmyadmin I can see that row I inserted. And yes, I am using the same database (checked it with config('database')).

Comment: It's certainly a strange problem. If you add a create right before the all() call in the code, do you see that newly created record in the all() results?

Comment: I am sorry, how do you mean? In my controller I have an index method with `$todos = Todo::all();` and it's just returning the view with that object. It is really odd because it really does work with Laravel development server, but does not with Homestead mapped link. And by the way, the mapped link also works, except that _loading from database_ part.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the homestead database might not be getting populated as expected, and that a good way to verify that would be to add a Todo:create([]); right above that Todo:all([]); to ensure there is data in the table in that runtime.